# What do docker-php-ext-configure, docker-php-ext-install and docker-php-ext-enable do?

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to set up a [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) web server using docker and was delighted to discover that the good folks over at `php` have put together [a docker container for php](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php).

Reading through the documentation I found three functions that will ostensibly assist me with the installation of php extensions;

- `docker-php-ext-configure`
- `docker-php-ext-install`
- `docker-php-ext-enable`

Being a complete newcomer to php and having tried and failed to enable php modules using a combination of `apk add` and `php.ini` hackery (resulting in `.so not found` errors), I'm ready to admit defeat and do it the proper way.

Unfortunately, the documentation is remarkable vague about what these commands do and how to use them:

> We provide the helper scripts docker-php-ext-configure,
>   docker-php-ext-install, and docker-php-ext-enable to more easily
>   install PHP extensions.

I tried to [google it as well](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+docker-php-ext-configure+do), but couldn't find any useful resources online either.

I'm now completely confused between what it means to install, configure and install a php extension, and how commands like `apk add php7-*` relate to all of this.

**Please explain what these functions do, and how you would use them to *enable* php extensions.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are helper scripts that helps one install php extensions from source

- not all extensions are available in a distribution native package manager or pecl
- even if these exist one may want to configure these differently or optimize

Talking about the scripts

- docker-php-ext-configure - configure an extension before you build it with `docker-php-ext-install`. It's executed by `docker-php-ext-install`, so one should use it if wants to override the defaults
- docker-php-ext-install - build extension from source, usually executes `docker-php-ext-configure` for build configuration, enables the extension (php.ini entry) by executing `docker-php-ext-enable` after all
- docker-php-ext-enable - enables an already installed extension by adding a specific entry to php.ini. Extensions installed with pecl or native package managers may not be enabled by default thus require this additional step. As mentioned above, extensions installed with `docker-php-ext-install` are being enabled automatically.

Answer (score 2):

these functions can help to set-up your PHP configuration, if per example 
you want to add opcache to your PHP configuation:

firstly you configure as below :

```
docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd \
```

and you install your configuration

```
  && docker-php-ext-install opcache
```

and then you can enable it

```
  && docker-php-ext-enable opcache
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you explain why you would configure _before_ installing, and also, does this mean we don't need to do `apt install php-ocache` as well?

Comment: in PHP if you would Enable GD Library in PHP with LibJPEG, you need to configure this for enabling the gd library, for the second if you need to implement the opcache it depends on which operating system on your docker container you use .

Comment: But absolutely you need to do apt install php-ocache for instaling this to your container.

Comment: So in order to use the `opcache` php extension, I would need to `apt-get install php-opcache`, then `docker-php-ext-configure`, then `docker-php-ext-install` and then `docker-php-ext-enable`?

Comment: Also, why would I do `apt-get install` when I have `docker-php-ext-install`? What's the difference?

Comment: According to documentation docker-php-ext-install is a helper script,  if your image is based on Ubuntu you need to use ap-get install php-opcache , but if you have an image based on centos you need to use yum install php-opcache.

Comment: Finally the helper script provide you can put docker-php-ext-install opcache and you'll get what you need .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and wasn't satisfied with the level of details of other answers.

The code of the `docker-php-ext-install` and other utilities is in the PHP docker images. Some examples:

- `php7.3-apache`: https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.3/buster/apache
- `php7.3-fpm`: https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.3/buster/fpm
- `php7.3-alpine`: https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.3/alpine3.12/fpm

`docker-php-ext-install` in `php7.3-fpm` has these interesting parts (omitting option parsing, etc.):

```
docker-php-source extract
cd /usr/src/php/ext

# skip usage, option parsing and checking the extension list

for ext in $exts; do
    cd "$ext"
    [ -e Makefile ] || docker-php-ext-configure "$ext"
    make -j"$j"
    make -j"$j" install
    find modules \
        -maxdepth 1 \
        -name '*.so' \
        -exec basename '{}' ';' \
            | xargs -r docker-php-ext-enable ${iniName:+--ini-name "$iniName"}
    make -j"$j" clean
    cd "$popDir"
done
```

So this means the `-j$(nproc)` I see everywhere specifies that the number of `make` jobs (commands) to run simultaneously is the same as the number of processors.